# different website links in the navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to have links to different websites in my nav bar but I'm stuck here.

```
<body>

<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#beeryoga">Beer Yoga</a></li>
    <li><a href="#dayinmylife">A Day in My Life</a></li>
</ul>
```

here's my css stylesheet also

```
ul {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;background-color:lightslategray;}
li {float:left;}
li a {display:block;color:white;text-align:center;padding: 14px 16px;text-decoration:none;}
li a:hover {background-color: #111;}
```

Comment: `but I'm stuck here.` Sorry, but I could not get this. If you want different website link, then you can add them directly in the `href`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the href to a link. For example:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a></li>
  <li><a href="another link">Beer Yoga</a></li>
  <li><a href="another link">A Day in My Life</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you change the href to https://stackoverflow.com/ instead of #home, the link will take you to https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to different links to different pages internally, make sure that you have matching `id` selectors for where you are linking to. For example:

These anchor tags will link to an `href` value of the `id` you have set on another page:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="beeryoga.html#beeryoga">Beer Yoga</a></li>
    <li><a href="dayinmylife.html#dayinmylife">A Day in My Life</a></li>
</ul>
```

Say this is beeryoga.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="beeryoga">
        <p>We are linking here!</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Say this is dayinmylife.html:

```
<body>
    <div id="dayinmylife">
        <p>We are also linking here!</p>
    </div>
</body>
```